# How to send input to servlet but not from action?

Tags: forms, post, servlets, action

I've got a form that I use to post some inputs to one site but I want to post them also to my servlet - is it even possible?

I've tried to do something with submit button, I mean executing onclick with function but something is not working properly

```
            <input type="submit" value="value1" onclick="afterSubmit()"/>
...some inputs...
        </form>
```

```
            form=document.getElementById("${initParam['posturl']}";
            function afterSubmit() {
                form.action="http://localhost:8080/url/servlet";
            }
        </script>
```

And my servlet:

````
public class sendThis extends HttpServlet {

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)   throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(request.getParameter("item_name_1"));
    }
}```

So when I click on submit button and then go to localhost:8080/url/servlet, I get this error:

HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed

Type Status Report
Message HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
Description The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.
````

Answer (score 1):

Add *doGet* method to your servlet and handle the request:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)   throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(request.getParameter("item_name_1"));
}
```